# Unable to remove double quotes

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a powershell script and it works great except the output has double quotes.  I have the last line that I thought would do the trick but it isn't working.

```
#CBRCust,StoreNum,StoreName,Load,Stop,Item,Quantity,Pack,Size,ItemDescription,UPC

$headers = "CBRCust","StoreNum","StoreName","Load","Stop","Item","Quantity","Pack","Size","ItemDescription","UPC"
$source = Import-Csv Sample.csv -Header $headers

#setup Output Table
$tabName = "Output"

#Create Table object
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable “$tabName”

#Define Columns
$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn ColumnTest1,([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn ColumnName2,([string])

#Add the Columns
$table.columns.add($col1)
$table.columns.add($col2)

#Index the source and create a new table.
foreach ($row in $source)
{
    $newrow = $table.NewRow()
    $newrow.ColumnTest1 = $row."CBRCust"
    $newrow.ColumnName2 = $row."StoreName"
    $table.Rows.Add($newrow)
}

#output Table
$table | format-table -AutoSize 
#save file
$table | Export-Csv -delimiter "`t"  Output.txt -NoTypeInformation  | % {$_.Replace('"','')} | Out-File output.csv
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove the double quotes? What issue are you trying to solve. The double quotes are fully compliant with the CSV file format standard and are actually a better default way to format a CSV than without them.

Comment: I am using this file to import order data into an application.  The vendor said the double quotes will mess up the import.  I guess I haven't tested their theory. Maybe I'll do that now...

Comment: You should tell them to make their app compliant with the CSV standard then if they want to use CSVs. Regardless I'm sure someone will post an answer on how to do it wrong for them. :) If not I will post something later when I have more time.

Comment: Nevermind, there is another question that has answers that will work for you.

Comment: `$table | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | foreach {$_.Replace('"','')} | Out-File output.csv`